# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I have a code that reads an excel data sheet (a table) into a `DataFrame` and convert a 'date' column (with values e.g. 20150508) into date time,

```
df['date'] = df['date'].astype(str)
dates = df['date'].to_datetime() // error occurs
```

I got a error,

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'
```

if I removed the line,

```
df['date'] = df['date'].astype(str)
```

the other line can run fine, I am wondering what is the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) method for `Series` only for `Index` objects it's the top-level method you want:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Comment: I think the default is to use the locale but generally it sniffs pretty well, it becomes problematic when you have entries that are ambiguous so it thinks the format is day first but really it's month first