# using 'to_datetime' on str object - in order to change dataframe column names

Tags: python, pandas

This is a follow up question to the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36407436/attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-to-datetime).

I have about 200 column names in a dataframe which need to be converted to datetime format.

My intital thought was to create a list of column names, and iterate thru the list, converting them as I go along, and then renaming the columns of the dataframe, using this list of converted names.  But from the previous question, I am not sure if I can apply to_datetime to a regular string element.  So this method won't work.

Is there anyway to easily convert all columns, or at least, selected columns, with to_datetime?

I do not see an axis to choose in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

pandas.to_datetime(arg, errors='raise', dayfirst=False, yearfirst=False, utc=None, box=True, format=None, exact=True, unit=None, infer_datetime_format=False, origin='unix')[source]¶

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) working only with `Series` (column of `DataFrame`), so possible solution are:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_datetime)
#alternative
#df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x))
```

Or:

```
for c in df.columns:
    df[c] = pd.to_datetime(df[c])
```

For convert column names:

```
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)
```

Comment: I tried df = df.apply(pd.to_datetime) but it is converting the values in the columns.  What I need is to convert the column names only.  This may not have been clear and I edited my question now.

Comment: @ZakS - Then need `df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)`